# dynamic Subject for Formspree

Tags: javascript, html

I need dynamic subject showing "customer_name" field.
I cant make it work for .html static page.

Maybe someone can guide whats wrong, thanks

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $sub = $("#_subject");
    $("#contact_name").on("input", function() {
        $sub.val($(this).val() + " (OAK)");
    });      
}, false);
```

```html
<form method="post" action="https://formspree.io/my@email.com">
    <div class="row2">
        <input type="hidden" name="_subject" id="_subject" value="OAK Landing (Bottom)" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_format" value="plain" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="thankyou.html" />
        <input type="text" name="_gotcha" style="display:none" />
        <div class="12u$"><input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name" id="contact_name" required="required"/></div>
        <div class="12u$"><input type="tel" name="Phone" placeholder="Phone Number" /></div>
        <div class="12u$"><input type="text" name="E-mail" placeholder="Email" /></div>
        <div class="12u$"><textarea name="Message" placeholder="Message"></textarea></div>
        <div class="12u$"><input type="submit" value="Send Message" /></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest to use **ajax** here. just collect all your form data in variables and manipulate as you want and send.

```
<form method="post" action="https://formspree.io/my@email.com">
<div class="row2">
 <input type="hidden" name="_subject" id="_subject" value="Landing(Bottom)" />
  <input type="hidden" name="_format" value="plain" />
   <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="thankyou.html" />
   <input type="text" name="_gotcha" style="display:none" />
           <div class="12u$"><input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name" id="contact_name" required="required"/></div>
           <div class="12u$"><input type="tel" name="Phone" id="phone_number" placeholder="Phone Number" /></div>
           <div class="12u$"><input type="text" name="E-mail" placeholder="Email" id="email_id" /></div>
            <div class="12u$"><textarea name="Message" placeholder="Message" id="message"></textarea></div>
            <div class="12u$"><input type="button" value="Send Message" id="submitButton" /></div>

   </div>
</form>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#submitButton').on('click', function() {

            var contact_name= $('#contact_name').val();
            var phone_number= $('#phone_number').val();
            var email_id= $('#email_id').val();
            var message= $('#message').val();
            var subject= $('#_subject').val();


            //send to formspree via ajax
            $.ajax({
                url:'https://formspree.io/my@email.com',
                method:'POST',
                data:{
                    name: contact_name,               
                    email: email_id,
                    phone: phone_number,
                    comments: message,
                    _subject: subject,
                },
                dataType:"json",
                success:function() {
                    alert('your mail has been sent!');               
                }   

            });     

        });

    });  

</script>
```

Comment: I placed your suggestion here here, but its not working. https://www.conexwest.com/specials/containers-for-rent.html

Answer (score 0):

I added an alert statement and it appears to be working fine at https://jsfiddle.net/fjmwfgy1/. It appears on the [link](https://www.conexwest.com/specials/containers-for-rent.html) you provided that you aren't importing in the jQuery library, which can be done by using one of the links on the [jQuery CDN](https://code.jquery.com/) page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $sub = $("#_subject");
    $("#contact_name").on("input", function() {
        $sub.val($(this).val() + " (OAK)");
        alert($sub.val());
    });      
}, false);
```